# Howto bind a RoutedCommand in a child?

Tags: wpf, xaml, command

I am having trouble binding a Command that is generated up the UI tree to a control. The following example illustrates my point, the `CommandBinding` in `Grid` does not act on the `InputBindings` in Window. Maybe I do not understand the point of commands, but I would like to have a nice solution for child controls to act on user input on the Window (any control on the Window).

```
<Window x:Class="SilverFit.Menu.Wpf.WpfWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="Close" Key="Escape"/>
        <MouseBinding Command="Close" MouseAction="RightClick" />
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <Grid Name="grid">
        <Grid.CommandBindings>
            <CommandBinding Command="Close" Executed="Close"/>
        </Grid.CommandBindings>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What object is acting as your command [*target*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx)? Whatever it is, it will need to be a child of the grid.

Comment: The command target is the Window in this example since the binding executes the Close method on the Window class.

Comment: Then the answer is that command bindings on the Grid can only see commands which are targeted at things *inside* the grid, or that binding a routed command in a child doesn't really make sense - because of the routed event model.